# Visual Studio 2017 froze while installing Nuget package and now my Xamarin project doesn't load

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0 only to the Android part of my Xamarin Forms project.

There's a popup with:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio is busy
We'll automatically report this delay to Microsoft...
```

No matter how long I wait, I can't open the project. What do I have to do to clear the cache to be able to load my project again?

Comment: Remove the package entry manually from the packages.config and the csproj file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I have to do to clear the cache to be able to load my project again?

To clear the nuget cache, you can download the NuGet command line tool from [nuget.org](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.9.2/nuget.exe).

Then, open a command prompt and cd to the directory to where nuget.exe is located.

You can list the local caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -list
```

You can clear all caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Check more info: [Managing the global packages, cache, and temp folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

Note: If your Visual Studio is not the latest version, please try to update it, MS fixed this issue on the some newer version.

Hope this helps.